# Saving an id to session

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to put the Product Id in session after saving the product, but I get a wrong id when I read the session.

```
foreach ($this->data['Address'] as $key => $ab) {
    $this->data['Product'][$key]['model'] = 'User';
    $this->data['Product'][$key]['foreign_key'] = $this->User->id;
    $this->Supplier->Brand->Type->create();
    $this->Supplier->Brand->Type->save($this->data['Product'][$key]);
    $this->Session->write('productId', $this->Supplier->Brand->Type->id);
}
```

How can I get the product id?

Comment: You are saving the last id in the set, as each consecutive loop overwrites the previous one. Is that not what you want?

Comment: yes i want to get the last id....

Answer (score 0):

try with the code

```
foreach ($this->data['Address'] as $key => $ab) 
 {
$this->data['Product'][$key]['model'] = 'User';
$this->data['Product'][$key]['foreign_key'] = $this->User->id;
$this->Supplier->Brand->Type->create();
$this->Supplier->Brand->Type->save($this->data['Product'][$key]);

$lastid = $this->Supplier->Brand->Type->getLastInsertID()

$this->Session->write('productId', $lastid);
}
```